# . .\Variables.ps1 returning CommandNotFound

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

I am trying to call a variable called $company from one powershell script called "Variables.ps1" into another powershell script in the same folder called "edit_website.ps1" at the top of "edit_website.ps1" i have `. .\variables.ps1` and then later on in the script i call on "$company" but it returns nothing leading me to think that the variable is not being loaded. When running the "edit_website" script it returns "the term '.\variables.ps1' is not recognized" Could anyone shine any light on why this is?

Comment: Which version PS? `$PSVersionTable.PSVersion` What are the relevant contents/sections of `variables.ps1` and `edit_website.ps1`?

Comment: @jscott Major: 4 Minor: 0 Build: -1 Revision: -1 All that is in Variables.ps1 is $Global:company = "company name" and in "edit_website.ps1" is '$text | out-file "c:/scripts/$company.html"'

Answer (score 0):

Solved by swapping out ./variables with the exact path to the powershell script.